# Can I integrate a decentralised wallet in a website in PHP?

Tags: wallet, development, php, website-integration, wallet-development

Can I integrate a decentralised wallet in a website in PHP? A decentralised wallet will act as service but I won't have access to the funds of users however users should be able to access their wallet through my website. If yes kindly share your suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to create self hosted bitcoin wallet? Maybe use a PHP library or JSON-RPC

Comment: PHP runs on the server... if users can click a button to send funds what stops you from clicking on the same button yourself?